# Nest js: Imported modules in Global module make it's services also global?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have three modules and I want their providers to be globaly in all nest js application by importing them to global module like this

```
@Global()
@Module({
imports: [SecurityModule, DataModule, ConfigHelperModule]
})
export class CoreServicesModule {}
```

does this really works ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them to both `imports` and `exports` and yes, it'll work